# How to achieve the opposite of an EntranceThemeTransition?

Tags: uwp

I am using an `EntranceThemeTransition` to slide in a `UserControl` from the right.

I would like to slide the user control back out to the right when the user dismissed the control, but I wasn't able to find an `ExitThemeTransition`.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d2fcd73-8420-4bb6-9f88-a22781d00c50/is-there-any-exitthemetransition-like-enterencethemetransition-for-the-gridtransition?forum=winappswithcsharp) suggests `ContentThemeTransition`, but I haven't got them to work yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are Transitions available for that.

What you could try is adding a RenderTransform on your UserControl, to change the postition yourself.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateUserControl" />
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
</UserControl>
```

Then use a Storyboard to control the translation.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardTranslate">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateUserControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty=/* X/Y direction */ To=/* use desired value */ Duration=/* add duration */>
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <SineEase />
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

When the control is dismissed start the Storyboard from code behind.

```
StoryboardTranslate.Begin();
```

Comment: Awesome, the `DoubleAnimation.To` and `From` properties let me achieve both a slide in and slide out.  Thanks Thomas!